# Maximum number of checks for merge sort if given a specific list.

Tags: algorithms

i have a list (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11), i need to find the worst case for maximum number of checks. now if i do a list (3,11,1,5,2,7,4,9,8,10) and then go like this
step:

```
1)(3,11) (1,5) (2,4) (7,9) (8,10) thats 5 checks
2)(1,3,5,11) (2,4,7,9) (8,10)  thats 6 checks
3)then (1,3,5,11) (2,4,7,8,9,10) thats 5 checks
4) and combine those into final list to get 9 more checks for total of 25 checks
```

is it possible to get ecen more worse case, i assume i cant do is to combine two lists into 4 like in step 2 and then combine those into list of 8 and then compare that to remaining list of 2 which gives me 27 checks.

Comment: I’m not sure why you have six checks in line 2). There are three for merging (3,11) and (1,5), but for merging the next pair of lists, (2,4) and (7,9), you only need two: compare 2 with 7 and place 2 into the result, then compare 4 with 7 and place 4, and that’s it. You ran out of elements in one sublist, so you put the remaining elements into the result without further comparisons. The worst-case situation in merge sort is when you never benefit from running out of values in one sublist before getting to the end of the other.

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be (2,7)(4,9)